# Trigger count SNMP traps

Tags: zabbix

I have SNMP trap sending message to Zabbix each time there's login failure. Message looks like:

```
20161207.134900 XCB-SNMP-MIB::xcbLoginFailure 0 (null) XCB-SNMP-MIB::description Authentication failed; username='sgsgsgsgsg' XCB-SNMP-MIB::peerAddress 10.138.1.31
```

I want to for example to get notification when in last 2 minutes I got more than 5 failed logins (so I got more than 5 traps), I tried to do expression like that:

```
{Testhost:snmptrap["XCB-SNMP-MIB::xcbLoginFailure"].count(2m)}>5
```

But it isn't working. Is there any mistake in expression, or should I look somewhere else for reason trigger isn't working? If expression is bad, how can I fix it?

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "isn't working"? Is your item receiving data correctly? If not, what does the error message in the frontend say (the red cross in the list of items for a host)? Similarly, does your trigger have a red cross in the list of triggers? If so, what is the error message?

Comment: there is no error message, evrything looks fine, just when I send few traps to check condition it didn't "click" like condition isn't fulfilled

Comment: Would it be possible to post some screenshots of data for this item and a corresponding screenshot of "Monitoring" -> "Events" for the same period of time?

Comment: Screenshoots added. I'm not sure this is what you asked for. I cannot find "Monitoring" -> "Events" tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work I changed:

```
{Testhost:snmptrap["XCB-SNMP-MIB::xcbLoginFailure"].count(2m)}>5
```

to:

```
{Testhost:snmptrap["XCB-SNMP-MIB::xcbLoginFailure"].count(2m,username)}>5
```

since I got 2 types of login failure messages:

```
20161208.131643 XCB-SNMP-MIB::xcbLoginFailure 0 (null) XCB-SNMP-MIB::description Authentication failed; username='dgdg' XCB-SNMP-MIB::peerAddress 10.138.1.31
```

and:

```
20161208.131641 XCB-SNMP-MIB::xcbLoginFailure 0 (null) XCB-SNMP-MIB::description Invalid username; username='' XCB-SNMP-MIB::peerAddress 10.138.1.31
```

and both of them contain "username", so I just count how many times that phraze occured.